# Little bit confused with Dependency Injection

Tags: php, symfony

I was reading http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html and I ended up confusing myself more then answering questions. I want to use a DI in my project so I can do proper testing and all the other wonderful things that come with DI.

However I was reading this and it all made sense until http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#avoiding-your-code-becoming-dependent-on-the-container

How can your code not be dependent on the container, isn't that how you access it?

Say you have a class with foo and a class with bar

```
class Bar {
    public function bar() { return 'hello world'; }
}

class Foo {
   public function __construct(\Bar $bar) { $this->bar = $bar; };
   public function foo() { return $this->bar->bar(); }
}
```

So you would add the dependency of Bar to Foo by

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container->register('foo', 'Foo')->addArgument(new Reference('Bar'));
```

Then you want to use Foo (print hello world) you would do something like

```
class Test {
    public function printHello($foo) {
        $foo->foo();
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->printHello($container->get('foo'));
```

Or something like that. But that document seems to say not to use $container->get? Unless I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood [Avoiding Your Code Becoming Dependent on the Container](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#avoiding-your-code-becoming-dependent-on-the-container). It discourage you from doing something like this:

```
class Foo
{

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        $bar = $this->container->get('bar');
        $bar->bar();
    }
}
```

In this way, your code is tied to a service container where service `bar` is present.

So, in general, only ask for what you need (which is `bar`), and don't ask for the whole universe (which is `service_container`).

By the way, without using `$container->get()`, you can still use something like `$bar = new Bar(); $foo = new Foo($bar);`

Comment: Ahh! That makes sense now.